# Restoring division algorithm for signed numbers

Tags: twos-complement, integer-division

I am trying to follow the division algorithm for signed numbers (2's complement representation) based on the algorithm described [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/106708579/2-s-Complement-Division-Algorithm#). This is the standard restoring method with M and AQ registers where M is the divisor, Q is the dividend and A is the signed extended of Q. When I want to apply the method for negative numbers, it doesn't work and I am confused where is the mistake exactly. I created a simple example for -11/3 which is shown below.

[image]

Any idea about that?

Update:

It seems that the method doesn't work for 1/(-1) where quotient is -1 and remainder is 0. The initial value of registers are `M=1111`, `A=0000` and `Q=0001`. In the first step, AQ is shifted to the left, so `A=0000` and Q=`001-`. Since A and M has different sign, `A=A+M=0000+1111=1111` which is -1. Since the sign of A has changed (previous 0 and now -1), we have to restore A to `0000` and insert `Q[0]=0` which results in `A=0000` and `Q=0010`.

By doing that three more times (four in total), `A=0001` and `Q=000-`. Again `A=A+M=0001+1111=0000`. Since the result is 0, we keep A and insert `Q[0]=1`. So, the final values are `A=0001` and `Q=0001`. As divisor and dividend signs are different, the quotient is the twos complement of Q and A is the remainder. Therefore, 1/(-1)=-1x(-1)+1 according to the algorithm. Something is wrong here...

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Restoring-division-for-signed-binary-number-RST-S_fig1_319302625  (there is a step on the end here)  SIGN = Dividend[MSB] XOR Divisor[MSB], if SIGN == 1 then 2's compliment Q (Q = ~Q + 1)

Comment: Your original reference source at scribd.com has at step 5... ; otherwise, the correct quotient is the two's compliment of Q.  This would make 3 into -3.